# SharePoint Online workflow pause until

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, timer-jobs, autohosted

As far as I know it could cause troubles to pause a workflow for a longer time, like a few months. And I can understand that it could be a problem to do so on an on premise installation.

But what about Autohosted Apps in Sharepoint Online.
Is it ok to start a workflow and then let it wait for half a year?

The alternative I have in mind is a Timer job running on Azure, but I think it would be much easier to use the Workflow.

Can someone please explain the differences to me?